# Using Google OAuth in a local network website

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-oauth

I have a website hosted on a Raspberry PI on my home local network. This website uses Google OAuth to access my Google user data.

I access this website from another machine in the local network. To do so, I've added a "mywebsever" entry in /etc/hosts pointing toward the Raspberry PI IP, and "mywebsever" is a javascript authorized origin in the site Google Cloud Platform console. It works fine.

It seems that this will stop working pretty soon, as Google communicated [OAuth URI validation rules](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies#secure-response-handling) that mandates for javascript origins to both have a domain under a TLD and use https.

I don't need my website to be accessible from the internet. Is there a way to still access my website from the local network, and retrieve my Google user data, without having to get a public domain?

Comment: Your link says that the redirect URL must have a **TLD** from the [public list](https://github.com/publicsuffix/list). It doesn't follow that the **FQDN** must be publicly *resolvable*. In fact, the domain you use might not even have to be registered, or you might not have to own it, although those may be good ideas.

Comment: Using a domain that has not been registered, would it be possible to get a valid certificate to turn HTTPS on?

Comment: No, you'd have to configure your client(s) to accept an invalid one.